# Is there a C++ STL class that works like a pipe?

Tags: c++, stl

In abstract terms a pipe is a stream/FIFO style container with a destructive read. It has a `read()` method that copies chunks of data all at once, and functions like `get` and `put` for single bytes. When the `read` or `get` returns though, the data that was copied out of the pipe is removed from the pipe's internal buffer - unlike a file or any other container type.

Most (all?) of the STL containers do not provide a similar `read()` in to a buffer command. Is there a fifo container type with a `pop_many()` member?

`stringstream` is about the closest thing I can think of since it maintains an internal read pointer and future reads will block until the stream fills up again. The container is empty from the API point of view, but the consumed data would have to be garbage collected manually.

Is there an equivalent container or stream class in C++ that does this, or is it a matter of roll-your-own (like in the stringstream example)?

Comment: I could put a loop around queue.pop(), but it's not efficient. I want to be able to remove large chunks of data, and the queue/fifo automatically resizes after I remove them.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I'm converting a class from using pipes to using a POSIX message queue. The API provides a stream-like read/write interface. I want to put a queue underneath, but retain the ability to read/write on top. I can easily do this with just a simple `char buffer[];` but I was wondering if C++ STL already had something in the standard libraries.

Comment: `std::deque` seems like it comes closest to suiting your purposes.  But the loop on `queue.pop()` wouldn't really be that inefficient if the backing container is a `deque`.  It's resizing operation is not expensive.

Comment: I did look at the deque, but "deques are not guaranteed to have all its elements in contiguous storage locations" which means there can't be a read member that moves large blocks of data in and out. OK, just saw your edit.

Comment: `std::copy(deque.begin(), deque.begin() + N, destination)`

Comment: You could have a deque of strings.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have already mentioned `std::deque` which at first glance appears to be your best choice.

If that doesn't work for you, what about using a `std::list<std::vector<unsigned char> >`. You put chunks on one vector at a time, and you `splice` them out into another list when you're popping. You'd have to provide a small amount of convenience wrapper code, and this might not be sufficient if you *don't* want to read all the elements of one of the sub-vectors at once.

Comment: Basically the API works like this: User waits on file descriptor for a message, when message arrives they call the Read methods to get the first byte to determine the message type (and thus the length of the rest of the message), then pass the object around and various parts of the application use the Read method to read the data into a char * buffer. So, for now, I'm looking at `std::stringstream`  because it gives me a read(char *, int) method, and it automatically decrements a get pointer. It also provides a readsome() method which doesn't block if the application tries to read more data.

Comment: BTW, Not my API. I would never do it this way!